# How to get order count of multiple store in single Shopify graphql call

Tags: graphql, shopify

I want to get multiple store details using Shopify graphql.
I tried like following but getting only current store details.

```
nodes(ids: ["gid://shopify/Shop/22954311758","gid://shopify/Shop/25747685469"]) {
    ... on Shop {
    id
    email
    }
    }
```

I know Shopify not provide other shop details like this because of security reason but I am looking for alternative to get multiple store details in a single graphql call.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as you need to pass Access-Token of particular store 
 in the header while making request. and there is no concept for sending multiple tokens in single request to be authorised using oAuth process.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible by default because of 2 restrictions:

1) You can't request two different end points ( you will have to request two stores GraphQL end points at the same time )

2) You will need to pass two different Access Tokens in the header request for each store.

---

In order to achieve this you will need to create a custom GraphQL server that will handle the request from the two different stores and pass them to your request. So in fact you are making two request in the background but your one will be a single one.

In addition if you make a separate GraphQL server you wont get any advantages in speed unless you cache the requests

But I find this solution a massive overkill in the current state of the request in your question. If you require multiply request of a such matter yes, but if you want to decrease a single request instead of making two just make the two instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, it is not possible because I want this for multiple stores not for just 2. It is also dynamic from 2 stores to 120 stores.